# How to take date time difference by milliseconds in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

In my requirement, I need to take the difference between date time by milliseconds. its most of the time receiving correctly, but in sometimes, it shows minus value.

in my table I'm storing `EXPIREDDATE` as follows, to update EXPIREDDATE time by 2 hours

```
UPDATE nd_user_encode_keys
SET EXPIREDDATE = SYSDATE + ( 1 / 1440 * 120)  -- here 120 means 2 hours
```

and according to my SP, above query running before the below query.

```
SELECT (EXPIRYDATETIME - SYSDATE) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 as EXPIRYDATETIMEINMILISECONDS
```

My problem is most of the time result is **7200000** , but somtimes it shows minus value like this **-34932000** . what could be the reason for this issue. can someone please explain.

Comment: It makes no sense to use `SYSDATE`, which is a date and stores integer seconds (but not fractional seconds), and then to expect to be able to get a time difference in milliseconds. Why are you not using a `TIMESTAMP` data type and `SYSTIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Does your stored procedure sometimes take more than 2 hours to run?

Comment: @MT0 Actually I didn't know about that.  what should i use here instead of the `SYSDATE` ?

Comment: Is there perhaps a trigger on the table that is sometimes - maybe outside 'office hours' or something - modifying the value? Have you looked at what `expirydatetime` is actually being set to?

Comment: @MT0 yes, of course, its happening , but not 2hours, but 10-15mins? and returning this minus values. sometimes working perfectly without taking that much time and returning correct positive value.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `A - B`, then the result can be:

- 0, if `A = B`
- a positive number, if `A > B`
- a negative number, if `A < B`  --> that is your case

Why is `expirydatetime` less than `sysdate` and is that a valid value, I wouldn't know, but you should as it is your database, you're storing values into that table.

According to `update` statement you posted, and regarding the fact that `sysdate` won't return the same value "right now" as it did "a few moments ago", then it depends on *when* you ran that `update`.

Therefore, I presume it is about time difference between `update` and `select`.

Comment: `A < B` is impossible scenario. this issue happening time to time, when I execute this sometimes working perfectly, but in sometimes its take 1-2 minutes to execute the query and resulting minus value